# Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to connect to DynamoDB and getting this error
I am trying to use this db to test some Telegram bots but now its not essential, cause i just can't find any information how to fix this problem, mb i am stupid, but...

Code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let awsConfig = {
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "endpoint": "http://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
    "accessKeyId": "my_access_key",
    "secretAccesKey": "my_secret_access_key"
}

AWS.config.update(awsConfig);

let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let fetchOneByKey = function ()
{
    var params = 
    {
        TableName: "users",
        Key: {
            "id": 132
        }
    };
        docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }

        })
}

fetchOneByKey();
```

Tried some solutions from here, but nothing helped

Tried another solution:

```
let db = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2014-12-04'});

db.listTables({}, function(err, data) { // 2
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
 });
```

Catched this

data:
null

err:

```
Error: connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',
  errno: -4062,
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '169.254.169.254',
  port: 80,
  time: 2021-04-15T23:15:09.312Z,
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
    errno: -4062,
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '169.254.169.254',
    port: 80,
    time: 2021-04-15T23:15:09.312Z,
    originalError: {
      message: 'EC2 Metadata roleName request returned error',
      errno: -4062,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '169.254.169.254',
      port: 80,
      time: 2021-04-15T23:15:09.312Z,
      originalError: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You didn't include the actual error so it'll be really hard to help you out with your issue.  I'm guessing it has something to do with how async programming works.

Comment: Added error log